# Arranging 3 digits with replacement

Tags: probability

Digits {0,..9} to form a number of length 3 eg: 000, 010, 223, 989...

I understand that there are 10 numbers with 3 digits the same.

That there are 10*9*8 numbers with digits that are all different. 10 choices for first digit, 9 for second, 8 for third.

I'm confused why the number with two digits being the same is 10*9*3. I would have thought it would be 10P2 = 10!/8!, thinking there are 10 choices for the first digit, 9 for the second and 1 choice for third. Isn't this a permutation where order is implicit?

Thanks for any feedback this has been bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

There are 10 choices for the first digit, 9 for the second and 1 choice for third. This number (xyy) can be arranged in 3 different ways that's why you multiply by 3.

Answer (score 0):

A three-digit number with two repeated digits has two unique digits in total. Call the repeated digit $A$ and the single $B$. Then the number is specified given $A$, $B$ and the position of $B$. Since $(A,B)$ is ordered, that is
$$10_{\text{chose }A}\cdot 9_{\text{chose }B}\cdot 3_{\text{chose position of } B} = 10\ {\mathop{\mathrm P}}\ 2 \cdot \binom31$$